# Picker with custom Items [Xaml]

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to figure out a way how to create a picker with custom items in XAML. I am not sure if it is possible to achieve this task only using xaml. The picker would have to contain items that consist of a label and a switch. The code below illustrates the end goal:

```
<Picker Title="Picker title here">
<Picker.ItemsSource>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Hello Xamarin.Forms!" />
        <Switch />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Hello Xamarin.Forms2!" />
        <Switch />
    </StackLayout>
</Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. I think you can create a Popup with a ListView, where you have a ViewCell with all controls you need

Comment: I see. That sounds like a very good idea! I shall try that. Thank you for the advice!